# Restart python program whenever it encounters an exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I've got a selenium python script that occasionally runs into the following error at differing sections in my code:

```
Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from target frame detached
```

But when I encounter this error, if I re-run the program without changing anything, everything works again (so I know that it's either a problem with the website or the webdriver). In the meantime, I was wondering if there was a way to tell python to restart the program if a WebDriverException is encountered. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What's your command line look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `os.execv()`, according to [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-restart-script/), it enables a python script to be restarted, but you need to clean the buffers etc using this C-like function `sys.stdout.flush()`

```python
try:
    <your block of code>
except WebDriverException:
    print(<Your Error>)

    import os
    import sys

    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You could simply use the `os` module to do this: `os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)`
2. Use a `main()` function as a starting point for your program, and trigger that function again whenever you need to restart. Something like

```py
def foo1():
    return
def foo2():
    try:
        ...
    except:
        main()
def main():
    foo1()
    foo2()
if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the error occurs because it does not find a certain tag, you could put a wait

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```

or worst case

```
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

or

```
time.sleep(5)
```

which waits 5 seconds for the element to appear